# Change permission denied HTTP Status Code

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In django rest framework, whenever a permission is denied, it returns `401` to the client.

However this is very bad for items that are hidden. By sending `401` you acknowledge the user that infact, there is something there.

How can I instead return `404` in specific permissions? This one for example:

```
class IsVisibleOrSecretKey(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Owner can view no matter what, everyone else must specify secret_key if private
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        key = request.query_params.get('secret_key')
        return (
            obj.visibility != 'P'
            or
            request.user == obj.user
            or
            obj.secret_key == key
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the `DjangoObjectPermissions` in the Django Rest Framework [GitHub](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py#L146), you can [raise an `Http404`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py#L201). So instead of returning `True` or `False`, you return `True` if everything is good and then raise `Http404` if not:

```
from django.http import Http404

class IsVisibleOrSecretKey(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Owner can view no matter what, everyone else must specify secret_key if private
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        key = request.query_params.get('secret_key')
        if obj.visibility != 'P' or request.user == obj.user or obj.secret_key == key:
            return True
        else:
             raise Http404
```

Since `DjangoObjectPermissions` extends `BasePermission` (a few steps back) this shouldn't do anything unexpected - I've just tested to make sure it returns 404 though, I haven't used it outside of this context. Just a head's up to do some testing.